# Ho to update a variable that is defined in another component in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, components

i want to change a variable in other component in angular2. i tried like this:

```
 this.workorderService.changedValue = this.text
```

The **=** operator does not did the trick.
I searched on the internet and i found that you must use Eventmitter for this. I couldn't copy the examples given on the internet, because it wasn't clear.

Comment: You should create a service which holds your data in a stream (using rxjs).
Then create setters for every value, and every time you set a value, use Observable.next to warn every components that subscribed to that service that something has changed.

Comment: thanks for the answer. do you have any example?

Comment: Read this article from Cory Rylan ;) https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-2-observable-data-services. You may also want to look http://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-build-angular2-apps-using-rxjs-observable-data-services-pitfalls-to-avoid. Good luck !

Comment: Thanks, this article helped me out.

Comment: Glad to hear it :)